# How to Export CSV Using JSP & Servlets

Tags: jsp, csv, servlets

So I'm trying to make my JSP export a CSV file from a table.

But I have some problems:

My compiler's keep showing null pointer error, which still don't understand is it because of my CSV script error or I'm placing the script inside the wrong servlet method.

So far, here's my JSP.

```
<%@page import="jxl.write.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File" %>
<%@page import="jxl.*" %>


<%@page import="Model.FuzzyTopsis"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title> 
        Fuzzy Topsis Supplier Selection
    </title>

    <!-- Normalize -->
    <link href="assets/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/custom_style_00.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Font -->
    <link href="assets/css/font.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<!-- BODY STARTS HERE -->
<body>
    <section class="main_wrapper">           
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                </tr>

                <%
                   for (int i = 0; i < sNum; i++) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td>test-<%=i + 1%></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </table>
        </div>

        <form method="post" action="./Page_Five_Controller">
            <div class="sub_form_wrapper">
                <div class="sub_form_input">
                    <input class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" value="Download to XLS" name="submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </section>     
</body>
```

And here's my servlets:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    int sNum = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("sNum");

    //Variabel excel
    String header = "No, Nama Suppier";

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("result.csv");
    fileWriter.append(header.toString());
    fileWriter.append("\n");

    for(int i=0;i<sNum;i++){
        fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(i+1));
        fileWriter.append(",");
        fileWriter.append("TES");
        fileWriter.append("\n");
    }

    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();  
}
```

So can anyone please point out my mistake or show me how it's supposed to be done?

And, should you want to export your tables into CSV, is it right to to place the script inside the doPost() servlet function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is so messed up man. I am gonna answer your questions based on my assumptions. I hope this is what you want... So,

Assuming the servlet code you provided is for the servlet `Page_Five_Controller`, then the line you get the exception is this `int sNum = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("sNum");`. Thats because you have not set the value `sNum` as an attribute to the `session` implicit Object.

What I would do if i where you is to add all variables in the session object from within the jsp, and then going to the servlet retrieve those values from the session (since nothing changes in your view).

That would be something like this in jsp:

```
session.setAttribute("sName",sName);
session.setAttribute("stringTemp",stringTemp);
session.setAttribute("ccTemp",ccTemp);
session.setAttribute("sNum",sNum );
session.setAttribute("dNum",dNum );
session.setAttribute("cNum",cNum );
```

Then in your Servlet retrieve the values like this:

```
String[] sName = (String[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("sName");
String[] stringTemp = (String[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("stringTemp");
double[] ccTemp = (double[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("ccTemp");
int sNum = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("sNum");
int dNum = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("dNum");
int cNum = (Integer) request.getSession().getAttribute("cNum");
```

And then do the loop in your servlet and output the data.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry if my code caused misunderstanding, but actually I've already set those atributes in a session obj, on another servlets. So, that doesn't seem to be the source of the problem.

Should you want to export your tables into CSV, is it right to to place the script inside the doPost() servlet function?

Thank you.

Comment: But I'll edit my code on this page so it wouldn't lead to further misunderstanding.